# Click on a specific checkbox in a ListView using Espresso

Tags: android, listview, testing, android-espresso

I have a `ListView` where each row has a checkbox:

[image]

Now I want to click on the checkbox in the 4th row. I have the data model for each row, so I can easily use `onData()` to select a row with the given data. But how do I click on the checkbox in that row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your row layout allows clicking on the row to set the CheckBox, you can use this to click the ListView row:

```
onData(anything()).atPosition(4).perform(click());
```

Otherwise you can click directly on the CheckBox without knowing its ID:

```
onData(anything())
   .atPosition(4)
   .onChildView(withClassName(Matchers.containsString("CheckBox")))
   .perform(click());
```

You can then assert that the CheckBox is checked:

```
onData(anything())
   .atPosition(4)
   .onChildView(withClassName(Matchers.containsString("CheckBox")))
   .check(matches(isChecked()));
```

More info: https://github.com/shohrabuddin/Espresso

---

<sup>Note: To quickly add the imports for these methods, put the blinking cursor on the unresolved method, then do Android Studio ➔ <kbd>Help</kbd> ➔ <kbd>Find Action</kbd> ➔ search for `"show context action"` or `"show intention action"` ➔ click on the result option ➔ A popup window will appear ➔ click on `"Import static method ..."`. You can also assign a keyboard shortcut to "Show Context Actions". [More info here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/intention-actions.html). Another way is to enable `"Add unambiguous imports on the fly"` in the Settings.</sup>

Comment: Clicking on the row loads a "detail view". Holding on a row will select the check box or clicking the checkbox directly. Clicking the checkbox using the class name is a great idea.

Comment: Another benefit of using `Matchers.containsString("CheckBox")` is that it works on native `android.widget.CheckBox` as well as `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox`. Also, you can use `perform(longClick())` to send tap-and-hold events.

Answer (score 1):

After a little research, I found [`DataInteraction.atPosition()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/DataInteraction.html#atPosition(java.lang.Integer)) and [`DataInteraction.onChildView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/DataInteraction.html#onChildView(org.hamcrest.Matcher<android.view.View>)). For example, I can do

```
onData(instanceOf(BaseballCard.class))
            .atPosition(4)
            .onChildView(withId(R.id.checkmark))
            .perform(click());
```